# Where is the package.json when you build Selenium IDE?

Tags: firefox-addon, selenium-ide

I'm following the [instructions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Building-SeIDE) on how to build Selenium IDE. It works, and I get an xpi but there is no corresponding package.json. If I cd to the directory and do `jpm run` it just asks for the package.json.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can [Install Add-ons From File](http://www.accessfirefox.org/Install_Addon_Manually.php) which did the trick for me.